# ¿No hay ninguna forma existente de ejecutar una MAUI Blazor App en el navegador?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui

Según lo que he leído y entendido, MAUI Blazor es una tecnología que permite crear aplicaciones para web, Android, iOS, Windows, MacCatalyst y Tizen, pero al crear un proyecto no veo por ningún lado la forma de ejecutar el proyecto en el navegador, de verdad creo que debería haber alguna forma de ejecutar una MAUI Blazor App en el navegador mientras se desarrolla y no solo cuando se hostea. Si he entendido mal la forma en que funciona MAUI Blazor por favor explíquenme.

Estaba creando una MAUI App, luego me pasé a MAUI Blazor App para hacer el mismo proyecto web también, pero no encuentro como ir viéndolo en el navegador mientras lo desarrollo.

Comment: No lo ves en las opciones de ejecucion??

Comment: No, están todas las opciones de ejecución para desktop y mobile (emuladores que ya tengo configurados) pero no hay una opción de ejecución para el navegador.

Comment: No puedes, .NET MAUI Blazor es más grande que Blazor a secas, por ejemplo en .NET MAUI Blazor aún puedes usar XAML lo cual no es compatible con el navegador. Lo que puedes hacer es compartir el mismo código de un proyecto Blazor a uno MAUI

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas, leyendo bien la doc de Microsoft me di cuenta de lo que me comenta Yussef, no se puede ejecutar XAML en el navegador, y por lo tanto, un proyecto de Blazor Hybrid con .Net MAUI no se puede correr en el navegador.